# What are features in programming?

Tags: android, ios, architecture

want to create an app. There's constant talk about identifying features, but I don't understand what features are supposed to be. For instance, if I'm creating a math app and need to decide between addition, subtraction, division, and multiplication, is that also considered a feature?

Comment: This kind of question is more based on opinion rather than facts.

Comment: @ewokx I would think this is more the territory of [ell.se] (or maaaaaybe [english.se]).

Comment: @Amadan really?  Didn't think of that.  Thought the OP was trying to discuss  what constituted a feature and not the semantics of what features meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the context of of software development, features are the unique functionalities or capabilities that a software application presents to its users. for instance, the  math app has mathematical operation—be it addition, subtraction, division, or multiplication—is considered an individual feature. Features, at their core, embody the specific tasks or actions that users can execute within your application.

When you're delving into the identification of features for your app, you're essentially outlining what tasks the application will be equipped to perform, and the actions users will be able to carry out.

Hope that answers your question